# Add initial objects to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

Let's say I have `Queue` class that has a unique title and can hold a list of objects from my other class `Item`.

```
class Queue: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""

    let items = List<Item>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "title"
    }
}
```

I want to have `n` (probably 3-5) instances of `Queue` from the time the app gets installed available in the database, so I can access them at any time to add some `Item`s to the list of items. Is there a way to create those queues and save them to the database just once when the app gets first launched and where exactly in the code should I do it?

Comment: Do you also need to handle situation when user reinstalls the application?

Comment: Well, the data the user added to the lists can be deleted when the app gets uninstalled (which is the normal behaviour, I believe), but the empty queues have to get created again when the user reinstalls the application.

Comment: In such case solution by @pacification would be enough for you. Did you tried it?

Comment: It's working! I implemented the sulotion suggested by @pacification in my `AppDelegate` application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check somewhere at the start of your app how many `Queue`s you have right now:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

if realm.objects(Queue.self).isEmpty {
   // no items, so you should create n items 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add new object for Realm

```
class Task : Object {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var phone = ""
    @objc dynamic var address = ""
}
@IBAction func buttonSave(_ sender: Any) {
        let realm  = try! Realm()
        let user = Task()
        user.id = 0
        user.name = (txtName.text! as NSString) as String
        user.phone = (txtPhone.text! as NSString) as String
        user.address = (txtAddress.text! as NSString) as String
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(user)
            print("user:",user.name)
        }
    }
```